# Facebook shows </br> tag in description

Tags: php, facebook

I am showing data from database using php. everything works nicely but only break tag is appeared. I want og tag not to do that. how can I do that? these are my codes

```
<meta property="og:title"content="<?php echo $row->title ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image"content="jaintanews24.com/<?php echo $row->image ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description"content="<?php echo $row->description ?>"/>
```

Comment: `<?php if (!$code) {print "Where's your code?";}`

Comment: update you question and add  you code  ,, please

Comment: meta property="og:title"content="<?php echo $row->title ?>"/> <meta property="og:image"content="jaintanews24.com/<?php echo $row->image ?>"/> <meta property="og:description"content="<?php echo $row->description ?>"/>

Comment: @Nazmul - you have to show us your html output or look at your `$row->description` content.There is probably `<br>` inside.

Comment: in my database is set. e.g what Is your name?</br>my name is Nazmul.

Comment: Well that is wrong. You don't _store_ data in such a form, you only _format_ it when it gets _output_. That gives you the opportunity to easily apply no extra formatting at all in cases where it is inappropriate - such as `og:description`, which is plain text only.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is lacks debugging so far, you will probably be able to just use the following function to achieve the removal of 
 tags and other unsuitable tags for a description

```
strip_tags($row->description)
```

The php docs on strip_tags is available here: [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)